# Solve the Lyne puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction, no-computers

This puzzle comes from the game [Lyne](http://www.lynegame.com/).

---

The rules:

- Start and end at the shape with a white dot in the middle
- Only connect same colours together
- Lines cannot cross each other
- All points must be connected
- Grey points can have anything go through them
- Grey points must be connected with the amount shown of the dots in them.

The puzzle is complete when all points are connected and the lines go from the start to end points.

I struggled with this one so thought it would be fun to share, if anyone is interested it is F11 in the main game.

[image: Puzzle Lyne F11.]

---

The solution is easily google-able so please don't.

Comment: Side note: I'm unsure what tags to put on the question so if someone could tag it appropriately that'd be great.

Comment: Has this been down voted because the puzzle comes from elsewhere? Or is there another reason?

Comment: Perhaps because this is just a puzzle from a game

Comment: @n_palum I agree it could be a reason but I've seen questions from external sources posted on here before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now I solved it.

> I started at bottom right, red has a single path to get out of that corner. Then I added blue part on the right. I did not continue with deduction and did a guess how could red line continue and filled in yellow. Then I completed the blue.

This solution is not unique, a simple rearrangement in the center can be easily seen to suit.

> [image]